# Is it possible to play Flash animations in a QWebView in a 64 bit build of Qt on Mac OS X?

Tags: flash, qt, webkit, qtwebkit, qwebview

Previously it wasn't possible to play Flash animations in a QWebView in a 64 bit build of Qt on Mac OS X because a 64 bit version of Adobe's Flash Player wasn't yet released.  See here:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5338

Since then Adobe has released Flash Player 11 in 64 bit. However, Flash animations still don't seem to work, I just get but the "blue lego block"instead of flash animations in pages I load.

I'm doing a basic build of Qt (i.e. configure, make, make install) and testing with the browser demo app.  There are no console error messages about not finding the correct architecture in the Flash Player plugin and Browser.app appears to load the plugin from disk fine, i.e. "info shared" in GDB outputs:

```
164 Flash Player                 - 0x11bc8e000        dyld Y Y /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Flash Player at 0x11bc8e000 (offset 0x11bc8e000)
165 FlashPlayer-10.6             - 0x11bc97000        dyld Y Y /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin/Contents/PlugIns/FlashPlayer-10.6.plugin/Contents/MacOS/FlashPlayer-10.6 at 0x11bc97000 (offset 0x11bc97000)
```

Am I doing something wrong with configuring Qt?  Has anyone else gotten this working?  I'm using the Qt browser demo app, so I'm (fairly) certain that it is properly turning on plugin support for it's QWebView.  Everything works fine if use a 32 bit build of Qt instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be coming a bit late, but here is [the solution](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72358) that a coworker of mine stumbled upon. You need to apply the patch "Preliminary fix for the problem based on Qt 4.8" that is attached to the bug report over the Qt 4.8.0 source and build it. It solved the "blue question mark lego" problem for me.

The patches are currently pending review by the WebKit and/or Qt teams, so these will or will not be included into the release versions of Qt / WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

Same experience here, although we did not try to build our app as a 32-bit app. If that's the only approach we may consider it although it would be a shame to have to revert just to get Flash support.

I confirmed that the FancyBrowser demo app has the same problem so I know it's not something that we're doing wrong. Works on Windows, not on Mac OS.